# Can I delete a commit from a branch which has already been applied for 2 branches before?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have been working on a project which has multiple branches. Before 1 month I pushed a commit to  the master branch. While deploying changes to the app my senior mistakenly approved my commit to master and test branches at the same time. Then me and my colleagues made some other commits on both branches. 
While trying to fix the problem I deleted the changes in my local but;
My question is : Can I delete all of the commits from only test branch (not from master) after the the date mistake done mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the commits done after the wrong commit, and how big.

I would probably look at doing an interactive rebase on the test branch and skip the commit for the merge.

However, I'm not sure how this would affect the test branch when you attempt to merge it back into master